# Removing Trailing Spaces in a List

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list that has many space and would like to remove the trailing spaces.

```
[ ,  , A, B, C, D,  ,  ,  ,  , E, C, D, E,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```

I would like to have it like this

```
[ ,  , A, B, C, D,  ,  ,  ,  , E, C, D, E]
```

I tried using trim by doing `arr.join().trim().split('')` but that also removed the starting spaces and

```
[A, B, C, D,  ,  ,  ,  , E, C, D, E]
```

How do I achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var l = [ '', '', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '', '', '', '', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'E', '', '', '', ''];
var result = l.reversed.skipWhile((s) => s.isEmpty).toList().reversed.toList();
```

Comment: Thank you these fixed my issue. I was using spaces so i switched ```s.isEmpty``` to ```s==" "```

Answer (score 0):

use trimRight() instead of trim() https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/trimRight.html

Comment: I just realized this implementation will not work when you have more than 1 character in an index